# retrieving table ID generically

Tags: entity-framework, linq, generics

tl;dr   I need a generic routine to retrieve the table ID for each table given some criteria.

It looks like the core of the problem is I need to create the parameter to Select from a string.
Select takes a selector as a parameter.

```
 Expression<Func<EntityType, TResult>> selector
```

I don't know how to create that from the name of the field I have as a string.

DETAILS
I have a base table, Clients, and a number of secondary (one-to-one) tables with various info about the individual clients. Let's call one ClientInfo.
The primary key of the base table is ClientID.
Each of the secondary tables also have a ClientID field, but the key is something like ClientInfoID.

I have a separate accessor for each table, with a base class that has generic routines like FindAll.

Here's an example that I'm trying to mimic:

```
public EntityType FindFirst(EntityType searchCriteria, ConnectionContext connectionContext)
{
    IsContextValid(connectionContext);
    if (searchCriteria == null) throw new ArgumentException("", "searchCriteria");

    using (var db = CreateDbContext<DbContextType>(connectionContext))
    {
        return db.Set<EntityType>().AsExpandable().Where(SetupFindMany(searchCriteria, connectionContext)).FirstOrDefault();
    } 
}
```

I have data I'm importing, that may update existing data.
I have populated all the entities, but can't Update the data because the entities don't know their existing ID.
I do know the ClientID.
I also have a routine that returns the key field(s) for a given entity, if that helps.
I want to have a generic routine that retrieves the Id for a given table and I'll assign it to the entity.

Here is what I have so far, but Select is complaining about the string parameter for the column name that I want.

```
public object GetKeyValue(EntityType searchCriteria, string key, ConnectionContext connectionContext)
{
    IsContextValid(connectionContext);
    if (searchCriteria == null)
        throw new ArgumentException("", "searchCriteria");
    List<string> keyNames = GetEntityPrimaryKeyName(searchCriteria, connectionContext);
    if (keyNames.Count > 0)
    {
        using (var db = CreateDbContext<DbContextType>(connectionContext))
        {
            return db.Set<EntityType>().AsExpandable().Where(SetupFindMany(searchCriteria, connectionContext)).Select(keyNames[0]).FirstOrDefault();
        }
    } 
}
```

Note that SetupFindMany just uses PredicateBuilder on the searchCriteria to return a predicate.

Normally, the parameter to Select would be something like (c => c.ClientID)

I need to parameterize ClientID in that statement. But it is not a string.

Answer (score 0):

When I started down this road, I thought it would be simple.
Lacking an abstract solution, I'll just create an abstract method in the base class and implement it in the descendent accessors where I can hard code the ID.